# Why iOS Provisioning Profile can expire?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

The iOS AdHoc Distribution Certificate can expire so what's the Apple reason of adding expiration date to a iOS provisioning profile?

Comment: So if your license runs out your profiles have a certain lifetime. So if you post an app, but then for whatever reason you stop updating / maintaining it (e.g. company closes) your apps will eventually expire, keeping the platform automatically free of outdated software.

Comment: Also you pay for your developer license, so it's only fair if you're license expires they eventually remove your apps. The same way that if I stop paying GoDaddy they will stop hosting my domain names. But for apps they do it less suddenly so the app user is not inconvenienced so it will still run until the profile expires.

Comment: @AntersBear in AppleStore it can't expire because on the moment of app uploading it's re-signed with Apple certificate.

Comment: Apple Developer Program (Individual or Organization) and Apple Enterprise Program Expiration Date ( 1 year  Paid ) account is one thing, the other are iOS Distribution Certificate ( 1 years ) and a Provisioning Profile ( 1 year )